# two output graphs in matplotlib scatterplot animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have some code to animate a scatterplot in matplotlib, everything runs smoothly, except that I end up with two output graphs at the end. One contains the desired animation, while the other is blank.

While it is probably a simple issue someone, I cannot see why, nor figure out why I am getting two graphs. Can anyone see what is giving me the "bogus" empty graph?
Cheers.

```
    import math, numpy, time, matplotlib, pyvisa
from pyvisa import visa
from matplotlib import pyplot, animation
import os.path

class Realtime_measurement_and_scatter_plot:


    def __init__(......):  

        self.animaiton = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.take_new_data_and_update_graph, init_func=self.initialise_graph, frames = self.number_of_measurements, interval=100, blit=False)





    def initialise_graph(self):

        self.figure = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()

        self.axes = matplotlib.pyplot.axes()

        self.axes.set_title("Realtime Plot")

        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []

        self.scatterplot = matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        return self.scatterplot,

    def take_new_data_and_update_graph(self, i):
...




        averaged_voltage = numpy.average(measured_voltages )
        new_time = float(i) * float( self.time_between_measurements )

        self.x_data = numpy.append( self.x_data, averaged_voltage )
        self.y_data = numpy.append( self.y_data , new_time )

        self.scatterplot = matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(self.x_data, self.y_data)



        return self.scatterplot,


   animation_instance = Realtime_measurement_and_scatter_plot(1000000, 1 , 1, 6, "Super_FUN_TEST.0",22)
   matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code here.  While many people are willing to help, few are willing to wade through this much code which is un-related to the actual problem.  Please only post the _minimum_ amount of code needed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks, code trimmed down now!

Comment: It should still be _fuctional_.  This looks broken because `__init__` uses attributes you don't create until `initialize_graph`.  There is also still too much code (for example, you can take almost everything out of `take_new_data_and_update_graph`.

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you mean about it looking broken. Changing this so that __init__ creates the figure, axes ect instead of them being created in intialize_graph removes the two output graphs problem. 
Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcaswell's comment about "**init** uses attributes you don't create until initialize_graph" 
prompted me to fix that.
Changing this so that init creates the figure, axes ect instead of them being created in intialize_graph removes the two output graphs problem; solving my problem!